# ansible nested json value extractaction

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to extract few keys and values from the below nested json

i want to extract domain.name and name when  cluster-member-names contains comm-gd-c1 and type=CpmiGatewayCluster

```
{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "checkpoint_servers_gateways": {
      "from": 1,
      "objects": [
        {
          "cluster-member-names": [
            "comm-gd-c1",
            "comm-gd-c2"
          ],
          "color": "black",
          "comments": "",
          "domain": {
            "domain-type": "domain",
            "name": "dom-gd-1",
            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
          },
          "groups": [],
          "hardware": "Open server",
          "icon": "NetworkObjects/cluster",
          "ipv4-address": "170.244.251.112",
          "management-blades": {},
          "meta-info": {
            "creation-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-04-30T13:40+01700",
              "posix": 1556611824910
            },
            "creator": "admin",
            "last-modifier": "admin",
            "last-modify-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-04-30T14:07+01700",
              "posix": 1556613459458
            },
            "lock": "unlocked",
            "validation-state": "ok"
          },
          "name": "Clus-01",
          "network-security-blades": {
            "firewall": true
          },
          "operating-system": "Gaia",
          "policy": {
            "access-policy-installation-date": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-08-14T12:14+01700",
              "posix": 1565765082106
            },
            "access-policy-installed": true,
            "access-policy-name": "Standard",
            "cluster-members-access-policy-revision": [
              {
                "name": "comm-gd-c2",
                "policy-name": "Standard",
                "revision": {
                  "application": "WEB_API",
                  "changes": 1,
                  "color": "black",
                  "comments": "",
                  "connection-mode": "read write",
                  "description": "",
                  "domain": {
                    "domain-type": "domain",
                    "name": "dom-gd-1",
                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                  },
                  "email": "",
                  "expired-session": false,
                  "icon": "Objects/worksession",
                  "in-work": false,
                  "ip-address": "127.0.0.1",
                  "last-login-time": {
                    "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                    "posix": 1565693111724
                  },
                  "locks": 1,
                  "meta-info": {
                    "creation-time": {
                      "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                      "posix": 1565693111730
                    },
                    "creator": "admin",
                    "last-modifier": "admin",
                    "last-modify-time": {
                      "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                      "posix": 15656931117016
                    },
                    "lock": "unlocked",
                    "validation-state": "ok"
                  },
                  "phone-number": "",
                  "publish-time": {
                    "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                    "posix": 15656931117014
                  },
                  "read-only": true,
                  "session-timeout": 600,
                  "state": "published",
                  "tags": [],
                  "type": "session",
                  "uid": "14bd921e-d766-4f71-a228-465b7f88d7b6",
                  "user-name": "admin"
                },
                "uid": "2639ab93-01ab-472c-a071-b24ad62eb49c"
              },
              {
                "name": "comm-gd-c1",
                "policy-name": "Standard",
                "revision": {
                  "application": "WEB_API",
                  "changes": 1,
                  "color": "black",
                  "comments": "",
                  "connection-mode": "read write",
                  "description": "",
                  "domain": {
                    "domain-type": "domain",
                    "name": "dom-gd-1",
                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                  },
                  "email": "",
                  "expired-session": false,
                  "icon": "Objects/worksession",
                  "in-work": false,
                  "ip-address": "127.0.0.1",
                  "last-login-time": {
                    "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                    "posix": 1565693111724
                  },
                  "locks": 1,
                  "meta-info": {
                    "creation-time": {
                      "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                      "posix": 1565693111730
                    },
                    "creator": "admin",
                    "last-modifier": "admin",
                    "last-modify-time": {
                      "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                      "posix": 15656931117016
                    },
                    "lock": "unlocked",
                    "validation-state": "ok"
                  },
                  "phone-number": "",
                  "publish-time": {
                    "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                    "posix": 15656931117014
                  },
                  "read-only": true,
                  "session-timeout": 600,
                  "state": "published",
                  "tags": [],
                  "type": "session",
                  "uid": "14bd921e-d766-4f71-a228-465b7f88d7b6",
                  "user-name": "admin"
                },
                "uid": "84ed0d02-4a01-4079-90c2-b4a119e64cf2"
              }
            ],
            "threat-policy-installed": false
          },
          "read-only": true,
          "sic-status": "uninitialized",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "CpmiGatewayCluster",
          "uid": "7a5f9f5c-b1703-4db6-b808-e8088ce6ab3c",
          "version": "R80.10",
          "vpn-encryption-domain": "addresses_behind_gw"
        },
        {
          "color": "black",
          "comments": "",
          "domain": {
            "domain-type": "domain",
            "name": "dom-gd-1",
            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
          },
          "groups": [],
          "hardware": "Open server",
          "icon": "NetworkObjects/gateway",
          "interfaces": [
            {
              "dynamic-ip": false,
              "interface-name": "eth0",
              "ipv4-address": "170.244.251.84",
              "ipv4-mask-length": 24,
              "ipv4-network-mask": "255.255.255.0",
              "topology": {
                "ip-address-behind-this-interface": "not defined",
                "leads-to-dmz": false,
                "leads-to-internet": false
              }
            }
          ],
          "ipv4-address": "170.244.251.84",
          "management-blades": {},
          "meta-info": {
            "creation-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-08-07T16:33+01700",
              "posix": 1565175815637
            },
            "creator": "admin",
            "last-modifier": "admin",
            "last-modify-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-08-07T16:36+01700",
              "posix": 1565175966098
            },
            "lock": "unlocked",
            "validation-state": "ok"
          },
          "name": "comm-gd-c10",
          "network-security-blades": {
            "firewall": true
          },
          "operating-system": "Gaia",
          "policy": {
            "access-policy-installation-date": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
              "posix": 1565693132506
            },
            "access-policy-installed": true,
            "access-policy-name": "Standard",
            "access-policy-revision": {
              "application": "WEB_API",
              "changes": 1,
              "color": "black",
              "comments": "",
              "connection-mode": "read write",
              "description": "",
              "domain": {
                "domain-type": "domain",
                "name": "dom-gd-1",
                "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
              },
              "email": "",
              "expired-session": false,
              "icon": "Objects/worksession",
              "in-work": false,
              "ip-address": "127.0.0.1",
              "last-login-time": {
                "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                "posix": 1565693100590
              },
              "locks": 1,
              "meta-info": {
                "creation-time": {
                  "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                  "posix": 15656931003170
                },
                "creator": "admin",
                "last-modifier": "admin",
                "last-modify-time": {
                  "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                  "posix": 1565693111462
                },
                "lock": "unlocked",
                "validation-state": "ok"
              },
              "phone-number": "",
              "publish-time": {
                "iso-8601": "2019-08-13T16:15+01700",
                "posix": 1565693111445
              },
              "read-only": true,
              "session-timeout": 600,
              "state": "published",
              "tags": [],
              "type": "session",
              "uid": "3f577564-7f28-45d4-a73c-d59bdecd064c",
              "user-name": "admin"
            },
            "threat-policy-installed": false
          },
          "read-only": true,
          "sic-status": "communicating",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "simple-gateway",
          "uid": "f267afcf-ff2a-4f34-babc-c6a76a59eb47",
          "version": "R80.10",
          "vpn-encryption-domain": "addresses_behind_gw"
        },
        {
          "color": "black",
          "comments": "Domain Management Server",
          "domain": {
            "domain-type": "domain",
            "name": "dom-gd-1",
            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
          },
          "groups": [],
          "hardware": "Other",
          "icon": "NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP",
          "ipv4-address": "170.244.251.111",
          "management-blades": {
            "logging-and-status": true,
            "network-policy-management": true
          },
          "meta-info": {
            "creation-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-04-26T16:31+01700",
              "posix": 1556276489829
            },
            "creator": "admin",
            "last-modifier": "admin",
            "last-modify-time": {
              "iso-8601": "2019-06-03T12:25+01700",
              "posix": 1559544910394
            },
            "lock": "unlocked",
            "validation-state": "ok"
          },
          "name": "dom_gd_1",
          "network-security-blades": {},
          "operating-system": "Gaia",
          "policy": {},
          "read-only": true,
          "sic-status": "communicating",
          "tags": [],
          "type": "CpmiHostCkp",
          "uid": "21472b8e-f337-4310-974b-786486a0b69c",
          "version": "R80.20"
        }
      ],
      "to": 8,
      "total": 8
    },
    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
  },
  "changed": false,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "details_level": "full"
    }
  }
}
```

for example 
if cluster-member-names == comm-gd-c1 and  type=CpmiGatewayCluster the query should return  below

```
"domain.name": "dom-gd-1
"name": "Clus-01"
"access-policy-name": "Standard"
```

i tried to do this withh jsonqury but failed

```
 - name: "set fact for policy pkg for list of devices"
    set_fact:
      pkgname: "{{ fullinvt  | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
      query: "results[?ansible_facts.checkpoint_servers_gateways.\"objects\"[?cluster-member-names[?contains(comm-gd-c1)]]]"
    tags: ADDLAG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify the data first. The task below

```
- set_fact:
    list1: "{{ list1|default([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ my_ansible_facts.checkpoint_servers_gateways.objects|
            json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: '[*].{names: "cluster-member-names",
                 type: type,
                 dname: domain.name,
                 name: name,
                 apname: policy."access-policy-name"}'

- debug:
    var: list1
```

give a list of dictionaries with the items of interest

```
"list1": [
    {
        "apname": "Standard", 
        "dname": "dom-gd-1", 
        "name": "Clus-01", 
        "names": [
            "comm-gd-c1", 
            "comm-gd-c2"
        ], 
        "type": "CpmiGatewayCluster"
    }, 
    {
        "apname": "Standard", 
        "dname": "dom-gd-1", 
        "name": "comm-gd-c10", 
        "names": null, 
        "type": "simple-gateway"
    }, 
    {
        "apname": null, 
        "dname": "dom-gd-1", 
        "name": "dom_gd_1", 
        "names": null, 
        "type": "CpmiHostCkp"
    }
]
```

In the next loop, we select the items that fulfill the conditions. The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "domain.name: {{ item.dname }},
          name: {{ item.name }},
          access-policy-name: {{ item.apname }}"
  loop: "{{ list1 }}"
  when:
    - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
    - "'comm-gd-c1' in item.names"
```

gives

```
"msg": "domain.name: dom-gd-1, name: Clus-01, access-policy-name: Standard"
```

Comment: Thanks for the update it is working as expected, but how we can use list of  variable in  `- comm-gd-c1 in item.names`  , i have to pass list of varible like comm-gd-c1,comm-gd-c2,comm-gd-c3 here

Comment: You're welcome. I don't understand the problem. You might want to open a new question. Simplify it and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724770/how-to-pass-second-list-in-to-play created