# How to pass second list in to play

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to apply list of items in to when condition and it is not working as expected

First list which is applied in the loop

```
 {
        "list2": [
            {
                "apname": "Standard",
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "cluster-01",
                "names": [
                    "device-cn-c1",
                    "device-cn-c2"
                ],
                "type": "CpmiGatewayclusterter"
            },
            {
                "apname": "PolicyPKG1",
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "cluster-cn-02",
                "names": [
                    "device-cn-4",
                    "device-cn-c3"
                ],
                "type": "CpmiGatewayclusterter"
            },
            {
                "apname": "Standard",
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "cluster-cn-3",
                "names": [
                    "device-cn-5",
                    "device-cn-6"
                ],
                "type": "CpmiGatewayclusterter"
            },
            {
                "apname": "Standard",
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "cluster-cn-4",
                "names": [
                    "device-cn-c7",
                    "device-cn-c8"
                ],
                "type": "CpmiGatewayclusterter"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "device-cn-4",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "device-cn-5",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "device-cn-6",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "device-cn-c1",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": "Standard",
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "device-cn-c10",
                "names": null,
                "type": "simple-gateway"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "device-cn-c2",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "device-cn-c3",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "device-cn-c7",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "device-cn-c8",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiclusterterMember"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-1",
                "name": "dom_cn_1",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiHostCkp"
            },
            {
                "apname": null,
                "dname": "dom-cn-2",
                "name": "dom_cn_2",
                "names": null,
                "type": "CpmiHostCkp"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using the above list (list2) in to the below task

```
  - name: Create a change request
    snow_record:
      state: present
      table: u_device
      username: admin
      password: password
      instance: dev970066
      data:
        u_name: "{{ item.name }}"
        u_domain: "{{ item.dname }}"
        u_policy: "{{ item.apname }}"
        u_cluster: "{{ item.name }}"
    loop: "{{ list2 }}"
    when:
      - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
      - "'device-cn-c1' in item.name
```

s"

above task is working as expected but you can see in the we condition passing a static value "device-cn-c1", i want to use different list of items instead of this static variable.

example list3 have multiple devices, i want to loop this list in when condition. (- "'device-cn-c1' in item.names")

```
  list3:
    - device-cn-c1
    - device-cn-c2
    - device-cn-c3
    - device-cn-c10
```

I want to use the same when condition

```
when:
  - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
  - "'device-cn-c1' in item.name
```

But  device name should be able to loop like below example

```
1.

when:
  - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
  - "'device-cn-c1' in item.names" 


    when:
      - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
      - "'device-cn-c2' in item.names"  


    when:
      - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
      - "'device-cn-c3' in item.names"  

    when:
      - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
      - "'device-cn-c4' in item.names"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the condition you're looking for?

```
when: list3|intersect(item.names)|length > 0
```

It is possible to loop include_tasks. For example (or rather a hint)

```
- include_tasks: loop1.yml
  loop: "{{ list2 }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
  when:
    - outer_item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
    - list3|intersect(outer_item.names)|length > 0

$ cat loop1.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item.apname }} - {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ list3|intersect(outer_item.names) }}"
```

---

Details. `list3|intersect(outer_item.names` creates a list of common items in in `list3` and `outer_item.names`. If this list is empty the loop will be skipped. If it's not empty file `loop1.yml` will be included. The loop inside this file will iterate over the common items.

See [Set Theory Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).

Comment: Hello Sir, no i want to use the  same condition `   when:
      - item.type == 'CpmiGatewayCluster'
      - "'device-cn-c1' in item.names"`

Comment: Hello Sir, no i want to use the  same condition i just updated the question with an example

Comment: The proposed code does exactly what you want. You might want to try it. I've added some details to the answer.